# Know the count of for-each loop before executing that loop

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, mpdf

How may i know that - In php how many times the foreach loop will get run, before that loop get executed..
In other words i want to know the count of that particular loop.
 I want to apply some different css  depends upon the count.

Comment: You can use count() or sizeof() PHP functions to know the size of the data you want to loop through.

Comment: What kind of content are you going to be looping over?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `count` to get the amount of numbers in your array.

Example:

```
$array = array('test1', 'test2');
echo count($array); // Echos '2'
```

Or if you want to be an engineer for-sorts you can set up something like so:

```
$array = array('test1', 'test2');
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) { $count++; }
```

And that can count it for you, and the `$count` variable will hold the count, hope this helped you.

Comment: Your second option is not correct OP says `Know the count of for-each loop before executing that loop` and your second option is executing the loop.

Comment: I know, just putting it out there for anyone else that may want to use it, and didn't want my question to be just `count($array)`, but thanks for the heads up @Indrajit :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply [count()](http://php.net/count) the array and use the output as a condition, like:

```
if (count($array) > 100) {
    // This is an array with more than 100 items, go for plan A
    $class = 'large';
} else {
    // This is an array with less than 100 items, go for plan B
    $class = 'small';
}

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo sprintf('<div id="%s" class="%s">%s</div>', $key, $class, $value);
}
```